# Prove that $xg(x)<\int_{0}^xg(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f(x)$ satisfy the differential equation$$\frac{d(f(x))}{dx}+f(x)=g(x)$$

where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous functions. Also it is known that $f(x)$ is a decreasing function of $x$ for all positive x.

Prove that $$xg(x)<\int_{0}^xg(x)dx$$

**My Attempt:**

Let $H(x)=xg(x)-\int_{0}^xg(x)dx$

$H'(x)=xg'(x)$

What can we say about $g(x)$ and $g'(x)$.

I think some information seems to be missing. If it is given that $f(0)\geq 0$ something may be worked out.

Comment: Some condition is missing. Take $f(x) = e^{-x}$, then we have $xg(x) = \int_0^x g(t)\,dt$ for all $x$.

Comment: $\int_0^x g(x) dx$ is bad form since you use $x$ as an endpoint and as a bound variable of integration. You should write $\int_0^x g(t)dt$ or something like that. For example, see any formulation of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Answer (score 2):

we put $$g(x)=\frac{x+1}{(x-1)^{3}(x^{2}+1)}$$
We find $$xg(x)=\frac{x(x+1)}{(x-1)^{3}(x^{2}+1)}$$
and $$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}\frac{(x+1)}{(x-1)^{3}(x^{2}+1)}dx=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{x-1})+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{(x-1)^2})+\frac{1}{2}\tan(x)^{-1}$$
So
$$x\in ({-\infty},0)\quad  xg(x)\geq\int_{0}^{x}g(x)dx$$
And from it must be the conditions of the function or the limits of integration in order to achieve that relationship.